# What does Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT "mydomain" mean in Postman App?

Tags: postman, laravel-7

I'm trying to use Postman (Native App on Windows 7 64 bits) to test my routes in Laravel 7, but the next error appears (Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT "my domain"). I'm not sure what happens but with Postman extension on chrome(deprecated) everything is fine. I don´t find any information about it.

btw, I'm sorry for any grammar mistakes because this is not my native language :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the URL/route you gave Postman is incorrect or non-existent?